# How to create a letter scoring function that scores vowels differently from consonants

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm trying to create a word scoring algorithm that gives one point for every consonant and 3 point for every vowel. But every attempt I've tried has failed which means something isn't mentally clicking for me and I need help understanding what I'm doing wrong

I've searched all over the web and found numerous ways to check letters of a word and count vowels, which I've tried customizing and using for my scoring algorithm and I still keep getting the wrong scoring output when testing each approach. I've looked at using iterative approached and using regular expressions. Someone was telling me that my fault is in my second loop but I'm not sure how to correct it.

```
//The attempt where apparently the second loop is the problem: 
vowelBonus= (word)=>{
  let score = 0;
  const vowels = ["a","e","i","o","u"];
  word = word.toLowerCase();
  for (letter in word){
    vowels.forEach((value)=>{
      if (letter === value){
        score += 3
      }else if(letter !== value){
        score += 1
      }
    })
    return score
  }
}

// An attempt using a regular expression which I kind of prefer after reading up on them

vowelBonus = (word)=>{
  let vowel = word.match(/[aeiou]/gi);
  let vCount = 0
  let consCount = 0
  let score = vCount + consCount
  if(vowel.length){
    vCount += 3
  }else if (!vowel.length){
    consCount =+ 1
  }
  return score
}

//I have about 3-5 other versions I've toyed around with but I'd like to stay in the ballpark of something like the two snippets I've pasted above. 

//One version keeps giving an output of 0. Another gives increments of 5, and I've had a few give a result of 1-5. I'm expecting the result to be 1pt for every consonant and 3pts for every vowel. Meaning if I type in the word "code", the result should be 8pts.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** Don't forget about edge cases, like if someone supplies a space in the word... Just something to consider...

**EDIT 2:** Added example using `regex` that ignores spaces if they are supplied..

Something like this should work.. I find it easiest to use the `Array.includes` method for things like this.

Let me know if you have any questions!

```js
function scoreWord(word) {
  // Ignores spaces
  return word.replace(/\s/g,'').toLowerCase().split("").reduce((a, i) => 
    a += ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"].includes(i) ? 3 : 1, 0);
}


function scoreWordSimplified(word) {
  // Ignores spaces; Simplified example
  let wordArray = word.replace(/\s/g, "").toLowerCase().split("");
  let vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
  let pointsForVowel = 3;
  let pointsForConsonant = 1;
  let finalScore = 0;

  wordArray.forEach(letter => {
    if (vowels.includes(letter)) {
      finalScore += pointsForVowel;
    } else {
      finalScore += pointsForConsonant;
    }
    /** Or you could do:
     * finalScore += vowels.includes(letter) ? pointsForVowel : pointsForConsonant;
     */
  });

  return finalScore;
}


let vowelBonus = (word)=>{
  // credit: @Code Maniac
  // Ignores spaces
  let _word = word.replace(/\s/g,'');
  let vowel = _word.match(/[aeiou]/gi);
  let wordLength = _word.length;
  let vowelLength = vowel && vowel.length;
  return vowel ? (wordLength - vowelLength) + vowelLength *3 : wordLength
}

let score1 = scoreWord("some word");
let score2 = vowelBonus("some word");
let score3 = scoreWordSimplified("some word");

console.log("scoreWord: ", score1);
console.log("vowelBonus: ", score2);
console.log("scoreWordSimplified: ", score3);
```

Comment: Thanks, and yes I thought about what if the user input had spaces or special characters in it. I was going to implement some kind of invalid input message, but I was told when the instructor test our assignments they will not be checking for that. Since I was having such a hard time with the vowel bonus scoring function in my code I decided to just not worry about it for the project. However I do plan on adding one in later just because I like to be thorough with my programs. Thanks for your explanation and sample solution though. I didn't think to use the Array.includes method.

Comment: One question I do have though. What's the purpose of the ? mark. I notice that every response to this post uses it, I tried to look it up under the operator list in the documentation and couldn't find it. Is the only used with regular expressions or is this an operator like ===, !==, +, -, etc

Comment: The question mark is known as the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) - not just the `?` but the `?` plus the `:` make up the ternary operator (commonly expressed as `?:`, which is a conditional operator. You use it like this: `let result = someCondition ? true : false` - it is commonly used as an "inline" `if`/`else` statement. `condition ? (if condition is true you wind up here) : (if condition is false you wind up here)`

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that using regex, as the other examples demonstrate, is nearly twice as fast as my example..

Comment: @Bizzy817 one last thing.. my original answer ignores spaces - I also added an example using `regex` (credit: @CodeManiac) but modified it so that it also ignores spaces... Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for that, and yes you're right. Using regex is twice as fast, and from what I can see looks cleaner. However, I've only been working with JavaScript for a month and two days today. A lot of the methods you used are easier for me to not just read, but understand what I'm reading. Since it a lot that we've covered so far in my training course. Although I'll definitely be studying the other solutions and researching more on regex, I'll be using your solution as my reference on how to code my function since its closer to my current skill level and understanding.

Comment: That is precisely why I went the route of using it as my answer :) I figured it would be easier for you to pick up on the logic. Which, in my opinion, is what really counts at such an early stage in learning.. I have also added another very simplified answer for you to dissect - this should help you even more.  Good luck with everything! Keep up the good work :)

Comment: Thanks for everything, and I will.

Answer (score 1):

It's simpler with regex:

```
(word)=>{
  let vowel = word.match(/[aeiou]/gi);
  vowelScore = 3 * vowel.length
  consScore = word.length - vowel.length
  return vowelScore + consScore
}
```

Comment: That it is, hence why I wanted to use regex instead of my first failed attempt. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Well there are lots of problems to notice in you code.

> In example 1

- Do not use `for .. in` for looping over the strings,
- when you iterate over string using `for ... in` it returns the index ( key ) of string not the value.
- You're returning value inside `for...in` after first iteration itself, whereas you need to return value after loop,
- Inside the loop you're looping over the `vowels` everytime and if the value is found you're adding `3` if not found you're adding `1`, but for each single characters you're looping on vowels which adds extra count than it should

> In example 2

- You're matching with regex and than if the length is greater than zero you're adding value just once whereas it should be `match.length * 3` and for the remaining length it should be `(word.length - match.length)`

so you can simply do this

```js
let vowelBonus = (word)=>{
  let vowel = word.match(/[aeiou]/gi);
  let wordLength = word.length
  let vowelLength = vowel && vowel.length
  return vowel ? (wordLength - vowelLength) + vowelLength *3 : wordLength
}

console.log(vowelBonus("aeiou"))
console.log(vowelBonus("abcd"))
console.log(vowelBonus("aeibcd"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on what I was doing wrong. I ran across so many different articles on the web trying to make sense on what I wasn't doing right. I was confused on the for...in loop on a string as well. I had a classmate tell me that it could not be used on a string because a string isn't an iterable. But looking on the documentation website it listed strings as an iterable and got confused even more. After he ran my code he saw that it did ran, but mentioned it wasn't the behavior I was looking for. Which also left me puzzled. You just shed light on everything I was confused on